# Does Google App Engine Flexible Environment support pyodbc?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

We currently have a Compute Engine server with a MSSQL database. We want to use App Engine and connect to our database within our compute engine.

I understand we can not do this using the Standard Environment, yet I am unclear if this can be accomplished using the Flexible environment.

We use pyodbc to connect to our database when using Python. I have read in a few places pyodbc does not work with App Engine but I have not found any clear answers.

Is it possible to connect to my database in Compute Engine using Google App Engine? Have any of you succeeded in doing this? When using python what library did you use to connect to the database?

Answer (score 2):

Apps in the standard environment run in a sandbox and this restricts some things your app can do like it can only use [whitelisted binary libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27)

> In contrast, the flexible environment runs your application in Docker containers on Google Compute Engine virtual machines (VMs), which have fewer restrictions. For example, you can use any programming language of your choice, write to disk, use any library you'd like, and even run multiple processes. The flexible environment also allows you to choose any Compute Engine machine type for your instances so that your application has access to more memory and CPU.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users#application_execution

So you shouldn't have any such restrictions on app engine flexible.